# How to use Arduino-Makefile with Sparkfun Pro Micro?

Tags: linux, build, makefile, arduino, cross-compiling

So, I am using Arduino-Makefile (https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile) and trying to program a 5V 16MHz Sparkfun Pro Micro (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12640).

I am using the versions of the Arduino libraries and Arduino-Makefile in the repository of the Linux distro I am using (Linux Mint 17.2). These versions are 1.0.5 and 1.3.1 respectively.

My file structure looks like this:

```
<project-root>/
    sparkfun/
        ... Sparkfun Arduino Addon Files (https://github.com/sparkfun/SF32u4_boards/)
    src/
        Makefile
        test.ino
```

My test.ino is taken directly from here: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/pro-micro--fio-v3-hookup-guide#example-1-blinkies and looks like this:

```
/* Pro Micro Test Code
   by: Nathan Seidle
   modified by: Jim Lindblom
   SparkFun Electronics
   date: September 16, 2013
   license: Public Domain - please use this code however you'd like.
   It's provided as a learning tool.

   This code is provided to show how to control the SparkFun
   ProMicro's TX and RX LEDs within a sketch. It also serves
   to explain the difference between Serial.print() and
   Serial1.print().
*/

int RXLED = 17;  // The RX LED has a defined Arduino pin
// The TX LED was not so lucky, we'll need to use pre-defined
// macros (TXLED1, TXLED0) to control that.
// (We could use the same macros for the RX LED too -- RXLED1,
//  and RXLED0.)

void setup()
{
 pinMode(RXLED, OUTPUT);  // Set RX LED as an output
 // TX LED is set as an output behind the scenes

 Serial.begin(9600); //This pipes to the serial monitor
 Serial1.begin(9600); //This is the UART, pipes to sensors attached to board
}

void loop()
{
 Serial.println("Hello world");  // Print "Hello World" to the Serial Monitor
 Serial1.println("Hello!");  // Print "Hello!" over hardware UART

 digitalWrite(RXLED, LOW);   // set the LED on
 TXLED0; //TX LED is not tied to a normally controlled pin
 delay(1000);              // wait for a second
 digitalWrite(RXLED, HIGH);    // set the LED off
 TXLED1;
 delay(1000);              // wait for a second
}
```

My Makefile, which is very short yet embarrassingly messy, looks like this:

```
MONITOR_PORT = /dev/ttyACM0

CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11 -I$(realpath ../sparkfun/avr/variants/promicro) -w -DUSB_VID=6991 -DUSB_PID=37381

# --- sparkfun pro micro
BOARD_TAG         = promicro16
ALTERNATE_CORE    = $(realpath ../sparkfun/avr)
ARDUINO_VAR_PATH = $(realpath ../sparkfun/avr/bootloaders)
BOARDS_TXT        = $(realpath ../sparkfun/avr/boards.txt)
BOOTLOADER_PARENT = $(realpath ../sparkfun/avr/bootloaders)
BOOTLOADER_PATH   = caterina
BOOTLOADER_FILE   = Caterina-promicro16.hex
ISP_PROG           = usbasp


USER_LIB_PATH := $(realpath ../lib)
include /usr/share/arduino/Arduino.mk
```

Everything builds fine, but the programmer complains when I try a `make upload`. The Pro Micro is `/dev/ttyACM0`, which I have confirmed by doing an `ls /dev/tty*` with the device both plugged in and not plugged in and comparing the outputs.

Here is the result of a straight up `make`:

```
-------------------------
Arduino.mk Configuration:
- [AUTODETECTED]       CURRENT_OS = LINUX 
- [COMPUTED]           ARDMK_DIR = /usr/share/arduino (relative to Common.mk)
- [AUTODETECTED]       ARDUINO_DIR = /usr/share/arduino 
- [AUTODETECTED]       ARDUINO_VERSION = 105 
- [DEFAULT]            ARDUINO_SKETCHBOOK = /home/kota/sketchbook 
- [BUNDLED]            AVR_TOOLS_DIR = /usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr (in Arduino distribution)
- [COMPUTED]           ARDUINO_LIB_PATH = /usr/share/arduino/libraries (from ARDUINO_DIR)
- [DEFAULT]            ARDUINO_CORE_PATH = /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino 
- [USER]               ALTERNATE_CORE = /home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr 
- [COMPUTED]           ALTERNATE_CORE_PATH = /home/kota/sketchbook/hardware//home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr  (from ARDUINO_SKETCHBOOK and ALTERNATE_CORE)
- [DEFAULT]            USER_LIB_PATH = /home/kota/sketchbook/libraries (in user sketchbook)
- [USER]               BOARD_TAG = promicro16 
- [COMPUTED]           OBJDIR = build-promicro16 (from BOARD_TAG)
- [ASSUMED]            MONITOR_BAUDRATE = 9600 
- [DEFAULT]            OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = s 
- [DEFAULT]            MCU_FLAG_NAME = mmcu 
- [DEFAULT]            CFLAGS_STD = -std=gnu99 
- [AUTODETECTED]       Size utility: AVR-aware for enhanced output
- [USER]               BOOTLOADER_PARENT = /home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/bootloaders 
-------------------------
mkdir -p build-promicro16
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -x c++ -include Arduino.h -MMD -c -std=c++11 -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/variants/promicro -w -DUSB_VID=6991 -DUSB_PID=37381 -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=105 -I. -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/bootloaders/promicro   -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Os -fno-exceptions   tinyimu.ino -o build-promicro16/tinyimu.o
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -MMD -c -std=c++11 -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/variants/promicro -w -DUSB_VID=6991 -DUSB_PID=37381 -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=105 -I. -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/bootloaders/promicro   -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Os   /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/WInterrupts.c -o build-promicro16/WInterrupts.o
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -MMD -c -std=c++11 -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/variants/promicro -w -DUSB_VID=6991 -DUSB_PID=37381 -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=105 -I. -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/bootloaders/promicro   -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Os   /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/wiring_analog.c -o build-promicro16/wiring_analog.o
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -MMD -c -std=c++11 -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/variants/promicro -w -DUSB_VID=6991 -DUSB_PID=37381 -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=105 -I. -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/bootloaders/promicro   -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Os   /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/wiring.c -o build-promicro16/wiring.o
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -MMD -c -std=c++11 -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/variants/promicro -w -DUSB_VID=6991 -DUSB_PID=37381 -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=105 -I. -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/bootloaders/promicro   -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Os   /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/wiring_digital.c -o build-promicro16/wiring_digital.o
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -MMD -c -std=c++11 -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/variants/promicro -w -DUSB_VID=6991 -DUSB_PID=37381 -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=105 -I. -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/bootloaders/promicro   -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Os   /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/wiring_pulse.c -o build-promicro16/wiring_pulse.o
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -MMD -c -std=c++11 -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/variants/promicro -w -DUSB_VID=6991 -DUSB_PID=37381 -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=105 -I. -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/bootloaders/promicro   -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Os   /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/wiring_shift.c -o build-promicro16/wiring_shift.o
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -MMD -c -std=c++11 -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/variants/promicro -w -DUSB_VID=6991 -DUSB_PID=37381 -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=105 -I. -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/bootloaders/promicro   -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Os -fno-exceptions   /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/CDC.cpp -o build-promicro16/CDC.o
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -MMD -c -std=c++11 -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/variants/promicro -w -DUSB_VID=6991 -DUSB_PID=37381 -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=105 -I. -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/bootloaders/promicro   -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Os -fno-exceptions   /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp -o build-promicro16/HardwareSerial.o
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -MMD -c -std=c++11 -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/variants/promicro -w -DUSB_VID=6991 -DUSB_PID=37381 -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=105 -I. -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/bootloaders/promicro   -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Os -fno-exceptions   /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/HID.cpp -o build-promicro16/HID.o
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -MMD -c -std=c++11 -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/variants/promicro -w -DUSB_VID=6991 -DUSB_PID=37381 -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=105 -I. -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/bootloaders/promicro   -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Os -fno-exceptions   /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/IPAddress.cpp -o build-promicro16/IPAddress.o
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -MMD -c -std=c++11 -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/variants/promicro -w -DUSB_VID=6991 -DUSB_PID=37381 -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=105 -I. -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/bootloaders/promicro   -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Os -fno-exceptions   /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/main.cpp -o build-promicro16/main.o
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -MMD -c -std=c++11 -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/variants/promicro -w -DUSB_VID=6991 -DUSB_PID=37381 -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=105 -I. -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/bootloaders/promicro   -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Os -fno-exceptions   /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/new.cpp -o build-promicro16/new.o
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -MMD -c -std=c++11 -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/variants/promicro -w -DUSB_VID=6991 -DUSB_PID=37381 -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=105 -I. -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/bootloaders/promicro   -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Os -fno-exceptions   /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Print.cpp -o build-promicro16/Print.o
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -MMD -c -std=c++11 -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/variants/promicro -w -DUSB_VID=6991 -DUSB_PID=37381 -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=105 -I. -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/bootloaders/promicro   -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Os -fno-exceptions   /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Stream.cpp -o build-promicro16/Stream.o
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -MMD -c -std=c++11 -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/variants/promicro -w -DUSB_VID=6991 -DUSB_PID=37381 -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=105 -I. -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/bootloaders/promicro   -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Os -fno-exceptions   /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Tone.cpp -o build-promicro16/Tone.o
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -MMD -c -std=c++11 -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/variants/promicro -w -DUSB_VID=6991 -DUSB_PID=37381 -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=105 -I. -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/bootloaders/promicro   -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Os -fno-exceptions   /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/USBCore.cpp -o build-promicro16/USBCore.o
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -MMD -c -std=c++11 -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/variants/promicro -w -DUSB_VID=6991 -DUSB_PID=37381 -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=105 -I. -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/bootloaders/promicro   -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Os -fno-exceptions   /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/WMath.cpp -o build-promicro16/WMath.o
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -MMD -c -std=c++11 -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/variants/promicro -w -DUSB_VID=6991 -DUSB_PID=37381 -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=105 -I. -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/bootloaders/promicro   -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Os -fno-exceptions   /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/WString.cpp -o build-promicro16/WString.o
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs build-promicro16/libcore.a  build-promicro16/WInterrupts.o  build-promicro16/wiring_analog.o  build-promicro16/wiring.o  build-promicro16/wiring_digital.o  build-promicro16/wiring_pulse.o  build-promicro16/wiring_shift.o  build-promicro16/CDC.o  build-promicro16/HardwareSerial.o  build-promicro16/HID.o  build-promicro16/IPAddress.o  build-promicro16/main.o  build-promicro16/new.o  build-promicro16/Print.o  build-promicro16/Stream.o  build-promicro16/Tone.o  build-promicro16/USBCore.o  build-promicro16/WMath.o  build-promicro16/WString.o    
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -mmcu=atmega32u4 -Wl,--gc-sections -Os    -o build-promicro16/src.elf build-promicro16/tinyimu.o build-promicro16/libcore.a  -lc -lm
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-objcopy -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom="alloc,load" \
                --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 -O ihex build-promicro16/src.elf build-promicro16/src.eep
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-objcopy: --change-section-lma .eeprom=0x0000000000000000 never used
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom build-promicro16/src.elf build-promicro16/src.hex

/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-size --mcu=atmega32u4 -C --format=avr build-promicro16/src.elf
AVR Memory Usage
----------------
Device: atmega32u4

Program:    4808 bytes (14.7% Full)
(.text + .data + .bootloader)

Data:        163 bytes (6.4% Full)
(.data + .bss + .noinit)
```

and the output of `make upload`:

```
-------------------------
Arduino.mk Configuration:
- [AUTODETECTED]       CURRENT_OS = LINUX 
- [COMPUTED]           ARDMK_DIR = /usr/share/arduino (relative to Common.mk)
- [AUTODETECTED]       ARDUINO_DIR = /usr/share/arduino 
- [AUTODETECTED]       ARDUINO_VERSION = 105 
- [DEFAULT]            ARDUINO_SKETCHBOOK = /home/kota/sketchbook 
- [BUNDLED]            AVR_TOOLS_DIR = /usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr (in Arduino distribution)
- [COMPUTED]           ARDUINO_LIB_PATH = /usr/share/arduino/libraries (from ARDUINO_DIR)
- [DEFAULT]            ARDUINO_CORE_PATH = /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino 
- [USER]               ALTERNATE_CORE = /home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr 
- [COMPUTED]           ALTERNATE_CORE_PATH = /home/kota/sketchbook/hardware//home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr  (from ARDUINO_SKETCHBOOK and ALTERNATE_CORE)
- [DEFAULT]            USER_LIB_PATH = /home/kota/sketchbook/libraries (in user sketchbook)
- [USER]               BOARD_TAG = promicro16 
- [COMPUTED]           OBJDIR = build-promicro16 (from BOARD_TAG)
- [ASSUMED]            MONITOR_BAUDRATE = 9600 
- [DEFAULT]            OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = s 
- [DEFAULT]            MCU_FLAG_NAME = mmcu 
- [DEFAULT]            CFLAGS_STD = -std=gnu99 
- [AUTODETECTED]       Size utility: AVR-aware for enhanced output
- [USER]               BOOTLOADER_PARENT = /home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/sparkfun/avr/bootloaders 
-------------------------
make reset
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/src'
/usr/bin/ard-reset-arduino  /dev/ttyACM0
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/src'
make do_upload
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/src'
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/../avrdude -q -V -D -p atmega32u4 -C /usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/../avrdude.conf -c avr109 -b 57600 -P /dev/ttyACM0 \
                        -U flash:w:build-promicro16/src.hex:i

Connecting to programmer: .avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
make[1]: *** [do_upload] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/kota/Projects/tinyIMU/arduino/src'
make: *** [upload] Error 2
```

Now, because of the error, I figure it's something wrong with my configuration of the bootloader, but I am unsure. Maybe the programmer setting is wrong? I would appreciate any help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what worked for me.

First, go to the `hardware` folder in your Arduino sketchbook or create it if it does not exist. Then extract the [sparkfun addon files](https://github.com/sparkfun/SF32u4_boards/archive/master.zip) into the hardware folder. Your directory structure should look something like this:`$SKETCHBOOK_DIR/hardware/sparkfun/avr/`.

Then in your project directory use this makefile:

```
BOARD_TAG         = promicro16
ALTERNATE_CORE    = sparkfun

ARDUINO_DIR       = /usr/share/arduino

include $(ARDUINO_DIR)/Arduino.mk

upload2:
    avrdude -p atmega32u4 -P /dev/ttyACM0 -c avr109 -U flash:w:build-$(BOARD_TAG)/$(TARGET).hex
```

Then you should be able to run `make` and `make upload`. However, if your code does something that disables or overrides the default USB behaviour on the pro-micro, then Arduino-mk will not be able to reset the pro-micro into bootloader mode over USB. Instead short the `GND` and `RESET` pins twice to [get into bootloader mode](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/Arduino/Boards/32U4Note.pdf). Then `make upload2` flash the pro-micro (Note: the pro-micro only stays in bootloader mode for 8 seconds).